# Android Saving Shared Preferences using Backup Agent

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-backup-service

In my backupagent class I have this:

```
import android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper;
import android.app.backup.SharedPreferencesBackupHelper;

public class TheBackupAgent extends BackupAgentHelper {
    // The names of the SharedPreferences groups that the application maintains.  These
    // are the same strings that are passed to getSharedPreferences(String, int).
    static final String RECIPE_NAMES = "MyRecipeNames";
    static final String TEST = "testSave";

    // An arbitrary string used within the BackupAgentHelper implementation to
    // identify the SharedPreferencesBackupHelper's data.
    static final String MY_PREFS_BACKUP_KEY = "myprefs";

    // Simply allocate a helper and install it
    public void onCreate() {
        SharedPreferencesBackupHelper helper =
                new SharedPreferencesBackupHelper(this, TEST);
        addHelper(MY_PREFS_BACKUP_KEY, helper);
    }
}
```

I then have code to store a string into the testSave Shared Preferences and request a backup of the preferences:

```
public void requestBackup() {
    BackupManager bm = new BackupManager(this);
    bm.dataChanged();
}

public void saveRecipe (View v) {

    SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("testSave", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("testString", "This is my saved data.");
    editor.apply();

    requestBackup();
}
```

I then try to uninstall and reinstall the app and the saved data is gone. I have added the required code to the Manifest but it is not working. Does my app need to be on the play store? I really have no idea why it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can test your Backup agent using the `bmgr` tool which is part of your Android SDK (it's a command in `adb`). [See here how it can be used.](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/bmgr.html)

Comment: I have used adb to to manually backup and restore but the sharedPrefs are still null when I reinstall.

Comment: `editor.putString("testString", "This is my saved data.");` should be `editor.putString("myprefs", "This is my saved data.");` because that's the key name you give in the helper.